# Tkinter SpinBox getting the last value

Tags: tkinter

I have a tkinter spinbox widget.

```
    val = IntVar()
    Spinbox(from_=1, to=10, textvariable=val, command=lambda:self.Fn(val.get()))

    def Fn(self, v):
        print v
```

When the spinbox is clicked, it prints value of new spin box value.

Instead I want the previous spinbox value - which could be one above or one below the current value.

Is there a way i can get the previous value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to store the value, and print it the next time the function is called:

```
def Fn(self, v):
    result = self._oldvalue
    self._oldvalue = v
    print(result)
```

Don't forget to initialize `self._oldvalue` with some default value.

Comment: thnks.. should have been obvious :(